# Running Two Alamofire Requests in Sequence Swift

Tags: swift, asynchronous, alamofire, grand-central-dispatch

I am using Async library found [here](https://github.com/duemunk/Async) in order to wait for first alamofire request to complete before running my second from the ViewDidLoad. The library seems simple to use but I can never get the first request to wait. My code is as follows:

```
let group = AsyncGroup()

         group.utility
        {
            self.getToken()
        }

        group.wait()

        self.getDevices()
```

I would like the getToken function to complete the Alamofire request and its completion handler before moving on to the getDevices request. Both are very simple Alamofire requests.

**EDIT:**

This is the getToken request. The `token` variable is not getting updated with the alamofire response before second alamofire request is being called.

```
func getToken()

    {
        let httpheader: HTTPHeaders =

            [
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
        ]



        // Dev

        let param = [params here]


        Alamofire.request("url", method: .post, parameters: param, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers:httpheader).validate()
            .responseData { response in
                switch response.result {

                case .success:
                    if let data = response.data {

                        let xml = SWXMLHash.parse(data)

                        token = (xml["authResponse"] ["authToken"].element?.text)!

                    }

                case .failure:

                  print ("error")


                }


        }


    }
```

Comment: responseData returns immediately, after queueing the block to be executed at some later date (when the network operation completes), so wrapping the getToken call in AsyncGroup really isn't doing anything for you.  It's only synchronizing the return of the getToken call itself.

Comment: thats fine, I want the first alamofire request to load and execute immediately. I just want the second request to wait.

Comment: Easiest way will be to start the second request in the .responseData callback of the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getToken` looks more like:

```
func getToken(whenDone:(String?)->()) {
    let httpheader: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
    ]

    // Dev
    let param = [params here]

    Alamofire.request("url", method: .post, parameters: param, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers:httpheader).validate()
        .responseData { response in
            switch response.result {

            case .success:
                if let data = response.data {
                    let xml = SWXMLHash.parse(data)
                    token = (xml["authResponse"] ["authToken"].element?.text)!
                    whenDone(token)
                }

            case .failure:
                print ("error")
                whenDone(nil)
            }
    }
}
```

and the calling sequence just becomes:

```
getToken() { token ->
    guard let token = token else {
        return
    }

    getDevices()
}
```